# Onclick event not fire in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

in HTML I wrote on click function but this function is not executing anyone can please help me why is it happening and how can I resolve this error?

```js
function search() {
  console.log($("#search-form").serialize());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox dogbreed" name="breed[]" value="Airedale Terrier" onclick="search();">
```

Comment: I edited your question to place the code in a snippet. As you can see, it works absolutely fine. Please check the console for errors

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: are you sure your search() function is global?

Comment: please check my website http://newseinstein.com/Rwork/index.php/Listing it not working

Comment: @Rushabhshah if you check the console after clicking a checkbox on the left: `Uncaught ReferenceError: search is not defined` Presumably you need to move the `search()` function in to the scope of the window - or better yet, use an unobtrusive `change` event handler instead of the outdated `onclick` attribute. I'd also strongly suggest you fix the huge number of 404 errors your site generates

Comment: I don't even see the search method there

Comment: @Dragos it's at the end of the page, just before `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your function is declared before the element:

```
<head> 
    <script>
        var search=function(){
        console.log("hello world");
        };
    </sript>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox dogbreed" name="breed" value="Airedale Terrier" onclick="search()"/>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cce1jw3v/12/

Answer (score 0):

Onclick event is firing. But you are using `form.serialize()`. But checkbox is not inside . So `console.log()` is showing empty. Serialize will show when checkbox is `checked`.

```js
function search() {
  console.log($("#search-form").serialize());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="search-form">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox dogbreed" name="breed[]" value="Airedale Terrier" onclick="search()">
<label>Airedale Terrier</label>
```

Comment: Why -1 for this answer. It triggers function on click. Run code snippet

Comment: Downvote didn't come from me, but your assertion that the code is failing because the checkbox is not inside the form is completely false. If you check the OPs website you can see the error in the console is because the `search()` function is not in scope

Comment: Code snippet is not failing. It is triggering `search()` when click `checkbox`

Comment: Yeah, your code works, but is irrelevant to the problem the OP has

Answer (score -2):

What you have should work. See snippet.

```js
function search() {
  console.log($("#search-form").serialize());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="search-form">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox dogbreed" name="breed[]" value="Airedale Terrier" onclick="search();">
</form>
```

Comment: 'It works' is a comment not an answer. If the OP has an issue then clearly there is another underlying problem which this does not address